# Textbox similar to Facebook or Stack Exchange's ones for websites

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm pretty sure you all know what I'm referring to. It's like a textarea, and lets you enter stuff, and a little slide up menu will appear (kind of like an intellisense thing - displaying different words that it thinks you're going to type), and when u click it, or hit enter, it creates a little box inside the textarea with that word inside it. I need to find one of these (or make it myself), and I also need to grab those words entered and to some data stuff in Javascript before inserting them into the database. The "textarea" thing I'm talking about, incase I've got you completely lost, looks something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know if there are libraries/plugins etc that are available? Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct term for it is a `tag input`. Google has lots of results for them.

Here's one I've used before: http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html

Comment: Thank you heaps Rory. I wasn't getting any results on Google because I didn't know the correct term. :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. [Facebook style Tag input](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html)
2. [AutoComplete Examples](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/03/35-best-ajax-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-plugin-with-examples/)

Comment: Thanks heaps Ravi. I wasn't getting any results on Google 'cause I didn't know the correct term. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is not a textarea or input box, Contenteditable allows you to do this.

```
<div contenteditable="true"><span class="tag">tag1</span></div>
```

just like an input box you can write in a conteneditable div.